# Can I use WHERE clause within JOIN statement in Zend 2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have a normal SQL statement, which returns 15 records from the database. If I try to replicate the same thing using Zend 2, it returns 9 records. The difference is one WHERE / Conditional statement in one of the JOINs.
Let me explain...

Here is an actual SQL query:

```
SELECT FROM 
   BLABLA AS B (some other joins and then..)

       LEFT JOIN
   CITY AS C ON C.SERVICE_ID = B.SERVICE_ID
                AND C.DELETED = FALSE
   WHERE
       (B.PRODUCT_ID = 2219)
          AND (B.DELETED = FALSE);
```

As you can see, there is a WHERE / Conditional (AND C.DELETED = FALSE) clause within the JOIN statement and I want to do the same thing in Zend 2 DB select.

So I do this:

```
$select = $sql->select(); // This is Zend 2's select()

$select->from(
            ['B' => 'BLABLA']
        )

        ->columns(
            [
                'VALUE',
                'NOTES',
                'SERVICE_ID'
            ]
        )


        ->join(
            ['C' => 'CITY'],
            'C.SERVICE_ID = B.SERVICE_ID',
            'left'
        )

        ->where('C.DELETED = FALSE') // If I remove this line, it returns 15 records just like that plain SQL query, however doing so I lose this conditional statement. If I don't remove it, it returns 9 records.
        ->where('B.DELETED = FALSE')
        ->where('B.PRODUCT_ID = 2219');
```

What am I doing wrong? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

Apparently you need to wrap these sorts of things with an expression. So in my case:

```
->join(
     ['C' => 'CITY'],
     new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('C.SERVICE_ID = B.SERVICE_ID AND C.DELETED = FALSE'),
     'left'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below ZEND SQL code.

```
$select = $sql->select(); // This is Zend 2's select()

$select->from(
            ['B' => 'BLABLA']
        )

        ->columns(
            [
                'VALUE',
                'NOTES',
                'SERVICE_ID'
            ]
        )


        ->join(
            ['C' => 'CITY'],
            'C.SERVICE_ID = B.SERVICE_ID AND C.DELETED = FALSE',
            'left'
        )
        ->where('B.DELETED = FALSE')
        ->where('B.PRODUCT_ID = 2219');
```

Comment: Hi. If I do that, it gives me the following error: `Unknown column 'FALSE' in 'on clause'`. Thanks for the reply though!

Comment: ohh! Sorry for that. I think the way I suggest will work in Zend1 only. I assumed that this works in similar manner for zend1 and zend2. After your reply I compare the code library/Zend2/Db/Sql/Select.php and /libraries/Zend1/Db/Select.php code for join and found some changes. You can achieve the goal by passing the query in $db->query("Your Query");